# Special characters (Cyrillic, Chinese) to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I have a csv file, which contains some rows, which I want to insert to a MySQL table, using the `LOAD DATA INFILE` MySQL command. When I use the command, and the insert is ready, the special characters that are inserted are all messed up. The file stores the characters correctly (I think so, because when I open the file with an editor like EditPlus, the special characters are all mangled, but when opening with another editor, like EmEditor, the special characters appear correctly), the columns which will hold text with special characters are of colation `utf8_general_ci`, and they are either `varchar` columns or `text` columns. The table is an `InnoDB` table, with collation set to `utf8_general_ci`. I run the `LOAD DATA INFILE` command, from MariaDB command line, with the following parameters:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/csv/file' INTO TABLE tablename FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

*EDIT:* I also tried using the `SET NAMES "utf8";` command, before using the `LOAD DATA INFILE` one, with no success:|

Comment: For Chinese, you may need `utf8mb4` instead of `utf8`.  Some Emoji and Chinese characters are available only with utf8mb4.  (Cyrillic works fine in either.)

Comment: It seems that even the Chinese characters work now with the solution of deceze.

Comment: _Most_ Chinese characters work with `utf8`.  Only the 4-byte encodings fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL needs to know what encoding (character set) the file is saved in in order to read and interpret it correctly.

> The server uses the character set indicated by the
>   `character_set_database` system variable to interpret the information
>   in the file. `SET NAMES` and the setting of `character_set_client` do
>   not affect interpretation of input. If the contents of the input file
>   use a character set that differs from the default, it is usually
>   preferable to specify the character set of the file by using the
>   `CHARACTER SET` clause. A character set of `binary` specifies “no
>   conversion.”

Figure out what encoding your file is actually saved in, or explicitly save it in a specific encoding from your text editor (the editor that does interpret the characters correctly already), then add `CHARACTER SET ...` into the `LOAD DATA` statement. See the documentation for details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: Okay, right now trying with the `LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/csv/file' INTO TABLE tablename CHARACTER SET UTF8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';`. It will take a few minutes(~20) to complete, but I will get back as soon as it is ready.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your file is not UTF8. In your editor, when saving, check that your character encoding of the file is UTF8. The fact that the editor renders characters correctly, does not mean it is saved as UTF8. Character encoding is either an option when saving the file, either a file property somewhere in the menus (depends on the editor).

Comment: Hmm. I created the file using php, because I am transfering data from a PostgreSQL table to a MySQL table. I will check this, and get back with the results.

Comment: I've opened the file with EditPlus again, and now the characters appear correctly there also, and it says that the encoding of the file is UTF8. So I don't think this is the problem:(